# Getting specific data from a cursor

Tags: java, android

After running a `query` I have a data like below in a `cursor`

```
ID| TOPIC | TITLE | TYPE | NAME |
---------------------------------
1 | AB    | BCD   | ref  | Ferari|
----------------------------------
1 | AB    | BCD   | ref  | TOYOTA|
----------------------------------
2 | BC    | ABC   | notref| AUDI |
----------------------------------
2 | BC    | ABC    |notref| BMW  |
```

How can I get the NAME

Comment: how can I get the NAME ?? means

Comment: @Stacks28 Question updated. Please check.

Comment: u need to compare the consecutive rows and merge them accordingly m i right?

Comment: @Stacks28 Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the NAME.........and you can store all the datas into an arraylist......and retrieve the datas based upon the id value.......

Try this

```
ArrayList datas=new ArrayList();
ArrayList list=new ArrayList();
 String StoreTitle = "", StoreName="";
       cursor.moveToFirst();
       do{

           int getID = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id"));
           String Title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("TITLE"));
           String StoreName= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("NAME"));

           if(StoreTitle.equalsIgnoreCase(Title)){
               list=new ArrayList();
               String getTopic = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("TOPIC"));
               String getTitle = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("TITLE"));
               String getType = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("TYPE"));
               String getName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("NAME"));
               String name=StoreName+" "+getName;
               list.add(getTopic);
               list.add(getTitle );
               list.add(getType );
               list.add(name);
               datas.remove(getID);
               datas.add(getID ,list);
           }
           else
           {
               list=new ArrayList();
               String getTopic = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("TOPIC"));
               String getTitle = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("TITLE"));
               String getType = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("TYPE"));
               String getName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("NAME"));
               String name=StoreName+" "+getName;
               list.add(getTopic);
               list.add(getTitle );
               list.add(getType );
               list.add(name);
               datas.add(getID ,list);
           }
           StoreTitle = Title;

     }while(cursor.moveToNext());
```

Comment: you want all the details to put into an arraylist right.......see my updated answer

Comment: No, for 1 It will give only FERARI not TOYOTA.

Answer (score 0):

> Just modify else part, Keep track of position variable

```
else
{
String name=arraylist[position].getName;
name=name+" "+cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("Name"));
arraylist.setname(name);
}
```